# Spatial Join works when invoked through ArcMap GUI, but "Out of Memory Error" through ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.7

I want to join an input feature class (~11,000 polygons) with another feature class (~31,000,000 polygons). When I do this through ArcMaps 'Join - based on spatial location'  tool, it takes quite long but eventually succeeds (adding 'Sum' for all joined fields). I monitored memory consumption throughout and it seems 'healthy' to me (not even going close to my 64 GB RAM).

[image]

When I try to do the same with the follwing ArcPy code (as adapted from the documentation: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm):

```
outfc = "VG250_GEM_WBUILD"
inputFeature = "VG250_GEM"
joinFeature = "buildings_all"



fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()

# Add all fields from inputs.
fieldmappings.addTable(inputFeature)
fieldmappings.addTable(joinFeature)

# set sum area field
areaFieldIndex = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("Area")
fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(areaFieldIndex)

# Get the output field's properties as a field object
field = fieldmap.outputField

# Rename the field and pass the updated field object back into the field map
field.name = "sum_area"
field.aliasName = "sum_area"
fieldmap.outputField = field

# Set the merge rule to mean and then replace the old fieldmap in the mappings object
# with the updated one
fieldmap.mergeRule = "sum"
fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(areaFieldIndex, fieldmap)

# Delete fields that are no longer applicable
fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("osm_id"))
fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("name"))
fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("code"))
fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("type"))
fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("fclass"))

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(inputFeature, joinFeature, outfc, "#", "#", fieldmappings)
```

I obtain the following error message after around 10 minutes:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File "C:\tmp.py", line 259, in 
>   main()   File "C:\tmp.py", line 251, in main
>   calc()   File
>   "C:\tmp.py", line 105, in
>   calc
>   arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(inputFeature, joinFeature, outfc, "#", "#",
>   fieldmappings)   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 533, in
>   SpatialJoin     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000426: Out Of Memory
>   ERROR 000426: Out Of Memory Failed to execute (SpatialJoin).

What's strange about it is that, again, as far I can tell from the task manager, it's nowhere close from actually running out of my memory.

So, I believe I'm doing exactly the same thing through ArcPy as through the GUI, yet getting no result. What might cause these differences? How to troubleshout this?

Edit: I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 and the following Python version is used:

> 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:30:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact release of ArcGIS and whether you're using the  32-bit or 64-bit Python 2.7. Please use the Desktop documentation references when referring to  Python 2.7.

Comment: If you are running this in ArcCatalog as a geocprocessing tool, and having success then I suggest that you open the results panel and copy the python snippet from the the successful tool run. My guess is that you are not doing the same thing code wise, running in ArcCatalog versus writing a different script and running it outside of ArcCatalog aren't the same. Once you copy the python code snippet paste it into notepad, and then you can run this outside of ArcCatalog as a python script. Don't forget your imports.

Comment: It's not possible for a single ArcMap session to challenge the RAM of a 64GB system, since it is a 32-bit application, and has an effective ceiling of 2-3GB. 32-bit ArcPy is similarly limited. If you installed the 64-bit Background Geoprocessing extension, you'd have access to the full 64GB, but if this is a memory leak, even that might not matter. Instead of a spatial join, I'd recommend you try running a full Intersect, then pro-rate by area overlap, or, since 30m features is so large, convert your processing to SQL in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database.

Comment: @enolan, wow I didn't know about copying arcpy from the results panel, helps enormously! I'll try that.

Comment: @Vince the question remains why I works through the GUI no?

Comment: @enolan, running it through ArcCatalog's Spatial Join also fails. How is this different from the 'Join Data - based on spatial location' I posted in the screenshot above?

Comment: I created a separate question for this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346308/spatial-join-works-when-invoked-through-arcmap-gui-but-out-of-memory-error-wh