# Spatial Join works when invoked through ArcMap GUI, but "Out of Memory Error" when using ArcCatalog "Spatial Join" tool?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.7

(This question was inspired through the discussion here [Spatial Join works when invoked through ArcMap GUI, but "Out of Memory Error" through ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346245/spatial-join-works-when-invoked-through-arcmap-gui-but-out-of-memory-error-th))

I want to join an input feature class (~11,000 polygons) with another feature class (~31,000,000 polygons). When I do this trough ArcMaps 'Join - based on spatial location'  tool, it takes quite long but eventually succeeds (adding 'Sum' for all joined fields). I monitored memory consumption throughout and it seems 'healthy' to me (not even going close to my 64 GB RAM).

[image]

When I try to do the same with the 'Spatial Join' tool:

[image]

I run into an "Out of Memory" error after a few minutes. What's strange about it is that, again, as far I can tell from the task manager, it's nowhere close from actually running out of my memory.

So, I believe I'm doing exactly the same thing through ArcCatalog as through the ArcMap GUI, yet getting no result. What is the analog of the "Join Data" in terms of ArcCatalog functions?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of your earlier question. Whether run from ArcPy, ArcMap or ArcCatalog it appears that the Spatial Join tool is giving the Out of Memory error and remains the focus of your question.

Comment: Output name is wrong for tool.

Comment: Adding on to FelixIP's comment - add shp extension or place output in GDB

Comment: @PolyGeo I don't think it's a duplicate. The earlier question is about how arcpy might be causing troubles. Here it's now more specifically about ArcMap vs. ArcCatalog, and not whether I'm using the right parameters for arcpy or not.

Comment: @FelixIP and smiller, yes ok, I did that. The problem remains about out-of-memory, not the extension.

Comment: I think both questions are comparing the ArcMap GUI tool called Join Data with the Geoprocessing Framework tool called Spatial Join. No matter whether the Spatial Join tool is called from ArcMap, ArcCatalog or ArcPy it is still using the Geoprocessing Framework.

Comment: "Out of memory" doesn't mean the computer is out of memory, it means the (32-bit)  *process* is out of heap, which is a much smaller value. The *why* of memory errors could be highly subjective, and your goal is unclear -- Is this a bug report attempt? Are you willing to try 64-bit geoprocessing? With 341 billion potential combinations, it's easy to see how you could be flirting with memory issues.

Comment: My goal is to understand what's the analog of ArcMap 'Join' (that seems to work also for this amount of data) in terms of ArcCatalog tools, The final goal is to call it from arcpy.

Comment: But you've established that you *can't* call it from 32-bit ArcPy. There are plenty of places where *similar* functionality exists between the UI and ArcObjects code called by Python, but there are implemented differently. And those implementation details might be impacted by a 11k-by-31m join.

Comment: I've established I can't call the 'SpatialJoin' - fair enough. That's why I'm asking for the name of tool underlying 'Join - by spatial location', which I hope I'll be able to call.

Comment: There *isn't* a UI function that you can call from Python.  `SpatialJoin_analysis` is **the** tool. Try 64-bit geoprocessing. Either it works or you need another procedure (contact Tech Support either way)